# Windows 11 random applications keep crashing

Tags: memory, windows-11, crash

I have a Dell XPS 15 with Windows 11 Professional installed. For the first few months everything ran smoothly. Then I started seeing that applications suddenly stopped for no particular reason (Visual Studio, ShareX, Teams, Keypirinha, Chrome, etc.)

Usually it is more than one application at a time, and I cannot find anything of value in the Eventlog.

I suspected that it could be something faulty in my installation, so a week ago I did a complete reinstall of Windows 11 pro. Not just a reset but a complete wipe. Unfortunately the problem persists.

What can be the cause of this? Faulty memory modules? The laptop is quite new and I still have warranty on it, so if this is the case, is there any tool with which I can diagnose it?

Comment: Not just a reset but a complete wipe.    ...   Get the Dell Hardware diagnostic App and test all hardware.   Look very hard for incompatible software.  I have two production Windows 11 Pro machines both now over a year old and they work fine.

Comment: Also look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Maintenance, and pull down and look at Reliability History. There may be clues there for what is going wrong. I use this all the time.

Comment: Thanks! I will try all of it.

Comment: I cannot find any tool directly called "Dell Hardware diagnostic" - I keep getting directed to the SupportAssist tool. Is that the one you mean?

Comment: Try that, yes.   Ask Dell Support

Comment: @john I think you misunderstood. Dell Support Assist is the Dell support utility software, op is not talking about contacting Dell support, though they probably should.

Comment: I am now in contact with Dell support. If we find out anything that others can benefit from, I will post an answer to my own question. Thanks so far.